# How to get just the parent directory name of a specific file

Tags: java, groovy, java-io

How to get `ddd` from the path name where the test.java resides.

```
File file = new File("C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/test.java");
```

Comment: Is this for a generic file, or are you trying to get the parent directory of your source file?  If the latter, I'm not sure you understand Java compilation.  At runtime, `test.java` probably won't even exist on the computer where the program is being run.  It's the compiled `.class` file that is run.  So this will only work if you know where `ddd` is located, in which case there is no point in finding it programatically; just hard code it.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Use [`File`'s `getParentFile()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29) and `String.lastIndexOf()` to retrieve *just* the immediate parent directory.

Mark's comment is a better solution than`lastIndexOf()`:

```
file.getParentFile().getName();
```

These solutions only works if the file has a parent file (e.g., created via one of the file constructors taking a parent `File`). When `getParentFile()` is null you'll need to resort to using `lastIndexOf`, or use something like [Apache Commons' `FileNameUtils.getFullPath()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getFullPath%28java.lang.String%29):

```
FilenameUtils.getFullPathNoEndSeparator(file.getAbsolutePath());
=> C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd
```

There are several variants to retain/drop the prefix and trailing separator. You can either use the same `FilenameUtils` class to grab the name from the result, use `lastIndexOf`, etc.

Comment: You don't need `lastIndexOf`, just use `file.getParentFile().getName()`.

Comment: Just in case. If it returns `null` (if you created `File` instance with relative path) - try `file.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile().getName()`.

Comment: @MarkPeters That only works when the file was created with a parent File, though, which I'm guessing is relatively rarely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/915663/nidu its works, thanks

Answer (score 36):

Since Java 7 you have the new **[Paths api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html)**. The modern and cleanest solution is:

```
Paths.get("C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/test.java").getParent().toString();
```

Result would be:

```
C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd
```

Comment: after getParent(), you need toString(), getFileName returns a relative Path object, representing "test.java" only.

Answer (score 20):

```
File f = new File("C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/test.java");
System.out.println(f.getParentFile().getName())
```

`f.getParentFile()` can be null, so you should check it.

Comment: Just to make sure, the output is as follows: C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd

Answer (score 20):

Use below,

```
File file = new File("file/path");
String parentPath = file.getAbsoluteFile().getParent();
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that this method should have a parent set, even if the underlying file did not.

Answer (score 7):

If you have just String path and don't want to create new File object you can use something like:

```
public static String getParentDirPath(String fileOrDirPath) {
    boolean endsWithSlash = fileOrDirPath.endsWith(File.separator);
    return fileOrDirPath.substring(0, fileOrDirPath.lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar, 
            endsWithSlash ? fileOrDirPath.length() - 2 : fileOrDirPath.length() - 1));
}
```

Comment: This throws ArrayOutOfBoundsException if you are already on root location -"/"-

Answer (score 3):

```
File file = new File("C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/test.java");
File curentPath = new File(file.getParent());
//get current path "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/"
String currentFolder= currentPath.getName().toString();
//get name of file to string "ddd"
```

if you need to append folder "ddd" by another path use;

```
String currentFolder= "/" + currentPath.getName().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

From java 7 I would prefer to use Path. You only need to put path into:

```
Path dddDirectoryPath = Paths.get("C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/test.java");
```

and create some get method:

```
public String getLastDirectoryName(Path directoryPath) {
   int nameCount = directoryPath.getNameCount();
   return directoryPath.getName(nameCount - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Groovy:**

There is no need to create a `File` instance to parse the string in groovy. It can be done as follows:

```
String path = "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/test.java"
path.split('/')[-2]  // this will return ddd
```

The split will create the array `[C:, aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, test.java]` and index `-2` will point to entry before the last one, which in this case is `ddd`

Comment: It may surprise you, but there are still a lot of OS with different path separator characters.

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin :

```
 fun getFolderName() {
            
            val uri: Uri
            val cursor: Cursor?
    
            uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA)
            cursor = requireActivity().contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)
            if (cursor != null) {
                column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA)
            }
            
            while (cursor!!.moveToNext()) {
    
                absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data)
    
    
                val fileName: String = File(absolutePathOfImage).parentFile.name
    }
}
```

Comment: parentFile.name is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
    //get the parentfolder name
    File file = new File( System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/.");
    String parentPath = file.getParentFile().getName();
```