# Anchor href linking to hierarchically lower page

Tags: html, jsp, anchor

I'm using JSP to make some pages and I'm having trouble with anchor locations.

When I'm at page `/somepage/something` and on that page I want to link to page `/somepage/something/code`. Now, if I use this code:

```
<a href="<c:out value="${code}" />">Link</a>
```

it results in the link `<a href="http://my-server:port/somepage/code">Link</a>`.

If I use this code:

```
<a href="./<c:out value="${code}" />">Link</a>
```

it results in the link `<a href="http://my-server:port/somepage/code">Link</a>`.

And if I use this code:

```
<a href="<c:out value="/${code}" />">Link</a>
```

it results in the link `<a href="http://my-server:port/code">Link</a>`.

How can I make the link `<a href="http://my-server:port/somepage/something/code">Link</a>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the browser loads a page at `/somepage/something` (without a trailing slash), it interprets the path as "the file `something` in the directory `/somepage`". So when it sees links like

```
<a href="code">Link</a>
```

or

```
<a href="./code">Link</a>
```

it interprets them as being relative to the current directory, i.e. `/somepage`, which is why they resolve to `/somepage/code`.

If you want a (relative) link to `/somepage/something/code`, you will need a link like

```
<a href="something/code">Link</a>
```

(Note that if your page is at `/somepage/something/` (with a trailing slash), then the browser interprets `/somepage/something` as the directory. In this case, your first two attempts would work as expected.)

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about adding the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

That's the big problem with urls. I had the same issue using nodejs. finally I used the module URIjs to build an url.  You can find a suited lib for JSP, of just remove the things after lastest slash and add your `${code}`. See also [How to get just the parent directory name of a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197049/how-to-get-just-the-parent-directory-name-of-a-specific-file) and http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=459188

For example :

```
<%@ page import="java.io.File" %>

<%

  File f = new File(currentUrl);

%>
<a href="<%= f.getParent() + code %>">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the web framework you are using you can try one of the following:

```
<%
    String var = (String)pageContext.getRequest().getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
    request.setAttribute("forwardURI", var);
%>
<a href="${forwardURI}/${code}">Link</a>
```

or simply

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.requestURI}/${code}">Link</a>
```