# Java get parent of parent

Tags: java, file, directory

This is a very similar question to this one: [How to get just the parent directory name of a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197049/how-to-get-just-the-parent-directory-name-of-a-specific-file)

But there he wanted to get just the closest Parent directory, what I want is to be able to select other "Parents" such as:

**bbb** or **ccc** (considering the same example on the mentioned question)

File file = new File("C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/test.java");

I tried `file.getParent().getParent();` which didn't work.

Note: if possible I don't want to use regex on the path.

Comment: Well did `file.getParent().getParent()` not work? What happened? (If you've got an idea of what to do, and you've tried it, you should always say what happened.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`getParent()` returns a `String` - you can't call `getParent()` on a `String`.

Instead, you want [`getParentFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile--):

```
File grandparent = file.getParentFile().getParentFile();
```

Answer (score -2):

`getParent()` returns a String; `getParent()` returns a File;
eg:

```
Boolean fileNameChangedCheck = file.renameTo(
        new File(filePath.getParentFile(), "changedFileName"));
```

Here `filePath.getParentFile()` can't be replaced by `filePath.getParent()`;

There are more in JAVA API;

Comment: getParentFile() returns a File;

Comment: getParentFile() returns a File;

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question with an accepted answer, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is somehow substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. In this case, you've duplicated the exact information already given by [@jon-skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23791173/148680)