# Getting the full path of parent directory [java]

Tags: java

It should be rather easy, but I could not find a clean way to do so. I'm trying to get the parent full path of parent directory in a path. Consider the following path: `/bin/src/config/file`, I would like to get `/bin/src/config` in Java. So I get a string and need to get the full path (absolute path, not just the name and not relative) of the parent directory. What is the cleanest way to do so?

Comment: First result from google for  `java parent directory path` query gives [How to get just the parent directory name of a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8197049). Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: maybe the old [java.io.File](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html) or the not so old [java.nio.file.Path](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) classes (both part of java.base)

Answer (score 6):

You can use this, which will print the folder your file is in where `fileName` is your filename:

```
Path f = Paths.get(fileName);
System.out.println(f.getParent());
```

Eg for `String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\video.html"` the output is `C:\Users\Me\Documents`.