# How to check whether file exist in parent folder from the current directory?

Tags: java, file, parent-child

One of my file and the current path is in

```
D:\project\major\sample\pp.txt
```

Let's say I have a file in `major` folder say `lump.txt` as `(D:\project\major\lump.txt)`

I don't know the folder name of major but knows the file name (`lump.txt`) as it is dynamic which gives the exact folder path of pp.txt alone. I want to move to the previous 1 folder, in this case, the major folder.

So I get the file object by

```java
File file = new File("D:\\project\\major\\sample\\pp.txt")
```

Now I want to fetch the `lump.txt` file which is residing in the previous folder. But all of the below approaches doesn't fetch the file and always returns file doesn't exist

```
File file = new File(".\\sample\\lump.txt");
if(file.exists()) {
    Logger.info("file exist 1");
} else {
    Logger.info("file not exist 1");
}
file = new File(".\\.\\sample\\lump.txt");
if(file.exists()) {
    Logger.info("file exist 2");
} else {
    Logger.info("file not exist 2");
}
file = new File("..\\sample\\lump.txt");
if(file.exists()) {
    Logger.info("file exist 3");
} else {
    Logger.info("file not exist 3");
}
file = new File("...\\sample\\lump.txt");
if(file.exists()) {
    Logger.info("file exist 4");
} else {
    Logger.info("file not exist 4");
}
```

Please advise on how to resolve this problem. How to get the file?

Thanks

Comment: What is the current working directory when you start `java`? It should be `D:\project\major` as long I can see.

Comment: [How to get just the parent directory name of a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8197136/1518100)

Comment: I understand that you are trying to find the path to file `lump.txt`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Is this your requirement? Please check.

```
private static void fileParentDir() {
    File pp = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\major\\sample\\pp.txt");

    if(pp != null && pp.isFile() && pp.exists()){
        System.out.println("Current folder : " + pp.getParent());
        System.out.println("Parent folder : " + pp.getParentFile().getParent());
        System.out.println("Lump exists : " + new File(pp.getParentFile().getParent(), "lump.txt").exists());
    }
}
```

Output

```
Current folder : C:\Users\user\Documents\major\sample
Parent folder : C:\Users\user\Documents\major
Lump exists : true
```